# How to format data for Keras multi-input model served on Google AI Platform?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence

Is it possible to serve multi-input Keras models on Google AI Platform? If yes - how to format the data samples for online predictions? [Their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict) only covers single-input models taking JSON input like this:

```
{"instances": [
  {"values": [1, 2, 3, 4], "key": 1},
  {"values": [5, 6, 7, 8], "key": 2}
]}
```

How should it be for an AI model which takes 3 arrays on the input? I am guessing it could be something like this:

```
{"instances": [
  {"values": [[1, 2], [3], [4]], "key": 1}
  {"values": [[5, 6], [7], [8]], "key": 2}
]}
```

Am I right or am I wrong? Somebody please advise.

Comment: what is the difference between `[[1, 2], [3], [4]]` and `[1,2,3,4]` except its form of presentation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can serve multi-input models on GCP AI Platform using the Prediction service and the input JSON instances can be formatted like this:

```
{
   "instances":[
      {
         "input_1":[
            "..."
         ],
         "input_2":[
            "..."
         ],
         "input_3":[
            "..."
         ]
      },
      {
         "input_1":[
            "..."
         ],
         "input_2":[
            "..."
         ],
         "input_3":[
            "..."
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```